# Proving orthogonality of vectors in a complex vector space

Tags: real-analysis, inner-products, orthogonality

I'm taking a course in Real Analysis and have come across the following question which I initially thought looked quite simple:

Let $X$ be an inner product space over $\mathbb{K}$ ($\mathbb{K} = \mathbb{C}$ or $\mathbb{R}$) Show that x and y are orthogonal if and only if $||\lambda x  + \mu y||^2 = ||\lambda x||^2 + ||\mu y||^2$ for all $\mu, \lambda \in \mathbb{K}$.

I have proven the statement in one direction (starting with orthogonality and ending up with $||\lambda x  + \mu y||^2 = ||\lambda x||^2 + ||\mu y||^2$). However, I seem to be getting stuck trying to go in the other direction.
The following is what I have so far:

$||\lambda x  + \mu y||^2 = ||\lambda x||^2 + 2\bar{\lambda}\mu Re<x,y> + ||\mu y||^2$

Then we must have 2$\bar{\lambda}\mu Re<x,y> = 0$ for the desired equality to hold, and so $Re<x,y> = 0$.

However, for orthogonality I want $<x,y> = 0$ and can't see how I can make this next step.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The formula

$$ \|\lambda x + \mu y \|^2 = \|\lambda x \|^2+ \|\mu y \|^2 + 2 \bar \lambda \mu \operatorname{Re}\langle x, y \rangle$$

is not correct (the left hand side is real, while the right hand side may not be real). The correct formula is

$$  \|\lambda x + \mu y \|^2 = \|\lambda x \|^2+ \|\mu y \|^2 + 2  \operatorname{Re}\left( \bar \lambda \mu \langle x, y \rangle\right). $$

Answer (score 1):

We can assume

$$\| \lambda x + \mu y\|^2 = \|\lambda x\|^2+\|\mu y\|^2 $$

for all $\lambda, \mu \in \mathbb C$. Taking $\lambda = \mu =1$ gives

$$\|x+y\|^2 = \|x\|^2+\|y\|^2+\langle x, y \rangle + \langle y, x \rangle  $$

$$ =\|x\|^2+\|y\|^2 +\langle x, y \rangle + \overline{\langle x, y \rangle} = \|x\|^2+\|y\|^2+2 \operatorname{Re}\langle x, y \rangle$$

so that $\operatorname{Re}\langle x, y \rangle = 0$.

Now take $\lambda = i$, $\mu=1$. We obtain

$$\|ix+y\|^2 = \|ix\|^2+ \|y\|^2+\langle ix, y  \rangle + \langle y,ix \rangle$$

$$ =\|ix\|^2+\|y\|^2-i \langle x,y\rangle + i \langle y, x\rangle$$

$$=\|ix\|^2+\|y\|^2-i \left(\langle x,y\rangle - \overline{\langle x,y \rangle}\right) $$

$$ =\|ix\|^2+\|y\|^2- 2i \operatorname{Im}\langle x,y\rangle,$$

so that $\operatorname{Im}\langle x,y\rangle = 0.$